# Connecting Prismic.io and Meteor js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I want to use **[THIS](https://github.com/prismicio/javascript-kit)** javascript developer kit to pull in content into a meteor template.

For starters I am not sure what is preferable, to have my main meteor template built with spacebars

`{{title}}`

or using the predicate system for Prismic.io

`[:d = namespace.operator(<fragment>, <title>)]`

(*I know the predicates will have to be used somehow maybe store them in a variable and pass that to spacebars somehow.*)

Besides this, I have not even been able to get my Meteor app to run. I have the following html files

**test.html**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Prismic.io Javascript kit Test Suite</title>
</head>

<template name="test">
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</template>
```

**unit.html**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Prismic.io Javascript kit Test Suite</title>
</head>
<template name="quint">
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</template>
```

**doc.html**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Prismic.io Javascript kit Test Suite</title>
</head>
<template name ="doc">
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</template>
```

**fragments.html**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Prismic.io Javascript kit Test Suite</title>
</head>
<template name="fragments">
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</template>
```

Ok heres where my issues starts. I have all the javascript files from Prismic.io developer kit mentioned above in the client folder in `/src , /dis , /libs`

Meteor throws this long error below. The first reference in the error is future.js:183 with error **ReferenceError: window is not defined** My initial guess is this is a npm dependency that Meteor does not have. I am not sure, if so how can I get this development kit to work in Meteor. Or do I have to make http requests by scratch to prisimic.io/api with meteor.

Thanks! for any help in advanced.

```
W20141019-16:24:20.945(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20141019-16:24:20.999(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141019-16:24:20.999(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141019-16:24:21.000(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141019-16:24:21.000(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20141019-16:24:21.000(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/js/dist/prismic.io-1.0.10.min.js:2:6569
W20141019-16:24:21.000(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/js/dist/prismic.io-1.0.10.min.js:4:3
W20141019-16:24:21.001(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141019-16:24:21.001(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141019-16:24:21.001(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141019-16:24:21.001(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20141019-16:24:25.767(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20141019-16:24:25.769(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141019-16:24:25.770(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141019-16:24:25.770(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141019-16:24:25.770(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20141019-16:24:25.770(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/js/dist/prismic.io-1.0.10.min.js:2:6569
W20141019-16:24:25.771(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/js/dist/prismic.io-1.0.10.min.js:4:3
W20141019-16:24:25.771(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141019-16:24:25.771(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141019-16:24:25.771(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141019-16:24:25.771(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20141019-16:24:29.844(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20141019-16:24:29.846(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141019-16:24:29.846(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141019-16:24:29.847(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141019-16:24:29.847(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20141019-16:24:29.847(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/js/dist/prismic.io-1.0.10.min.js:2:6569
W20141019-16:24:29.848(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/js/dist/prismic.io-1.0.10.min.js:4:3
W20141019-16:24:29.848(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141019-16:24:29.848(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141019-16:24:29.848(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141019-16:24:29.848(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
W20141019-16:26:33.472(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20141019-16:26:33.474(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141019-16:26:33.475(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141019-16:26:33.475(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141019-16:26:33.475(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20141019-16:26:33.475(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/js/dist/prismic.io-1.0.10.min.js:2:6569
W20141019-16:26:33.476(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/js/dist/prismic.io-1.0.10.min.js:4:3
W20141019-16:26:33.476(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141019-16:26:33.476(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141019-16:26:33.476(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141019-16:26:33.477(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
W20141019-16:26:40.114(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20141019-16:26:40.116(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141019-16:26:40.116(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141019-16:26:40.117(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141019-16:26:40.117(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20141019-16:26:40.117(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/js/dist/prismic.io-1.0.10.min.js:2:6569
W20141019-16:26:40.117(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/js/dist/prismic.io-1.0.10.min.js:4:3
W20141019-16:26:40.118(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141019-16:26:40.118(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141019-16:26:40.118(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141019-16:26:40.118(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
W20141019-16:26:47.834(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20141019-16:26:47.836(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141019-16:26:47.836(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141019-16:26:47.837(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141019-16:26:47.837(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20141019-16:26:47.837(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/doc.js:529:3
W20141019-16:26:47.838(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/doc.js:531:3
W20141019-16:26:47.838(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141019-16:26:47.838(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141019-16:26:47.838(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141019-16:26:47.839(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20141019-16:26:51.795(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20141019-16:26:51.797(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141019-16:26:51.797(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141019-16:26:51.798(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141019-16:26:51.798(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20141019-16:26:51.798(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/doc.js:529:3
W20141019-16:26:51.798(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/doc.js:531:3
W20141019-16:26:51.798(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141019-16:26:51.799(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141019-16:26:51.799(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141019-16:26:51.799(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20141019-16:26:55.752(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20141019-16:26:55.754(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141019-16:26:55.755(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141019-16:26:55.755(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141019-16:26:55.755(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20141019-16:26:55.755(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/doc.js:529:3
W20141019-16:26:55.756(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/doc.js:531:3
W20141019-16:26:55.756(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141019-16:26:55.756(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141019-16:26:55.756(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141019-16:26:55.757(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
W20141019-16:59:50.767(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20141019-16:59:50.769(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141019-16:59:50.770(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141019-16:59:50.770(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141019-16:59:50.770(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20141019-16:59:50.770(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/doc.js:529:3
W20141019-16:59:50.771(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/doc.js:531:3
W20141019-16:59:50.771(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141019-16:59:50.771(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141019-16:59:50.771(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/anderskitson/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1q6jdah++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141019-16:59:50.772(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anderskitson/acornmade/mrskitson/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Comment: It seems like you have added client side code on the server side,

cause window is only available on client side,

happens with me everytime, as they are all javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what nicolsondsouza said, the Prismic kit is compatible with both client side (browser) and server side (Node.js).

Here is the line where we're detecting Node.js (at the end of each file):
https://github.com/prismicio/javascript-kit/blob/master/src/api.js#L1176

It appears that the test fails and we use "window" for the global object. I'm not sure how close Meteor is from Node.js, but this line needs to be adapted for compatibility with Meteor.

The other platform-specific code is the XHR, so there could be incompatibilities there as well:
https://github.com/prismicio/javascript-kit/blob/master/src/api.js#L26

We would love to support Meteor.js - we'll add it to our feature wish list, if you're in a hurry, a pull request would definitely help!

Comment: Just to grab your attention before I choose this answer. Which repository amd I submitting this pull request. I have never done such. And dont want to do it wrong.